# DBCException: Invalid number of points in LineString (found 1 - must be 0 or >= 2)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a postgres database with a table called `gps_points`. This table has a column `index`, `latitude` and `longitude`

Using the following command I have been able to add and populate a point geometry column `point_geom`.

```
ALTER TABLE gps_points ADD COLUMN point_geom geometry(Point, 4326);
UPDATE gps_points SET point_geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

[image]

Now I would like to create linestrings based on these points. I was hoping I could achieve this by the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE gps_points ADD COLUMN line_geom geometry(Linestring,4326);
INSERT INTO gps_points (line_geom)
SELECT ST_MakeLine (gps.point_geom ORDER BY index) AS line_geom
    FROM gps_points AS gps
    GROUP BY gps.index;
```

However, all rows in the resulting column show the following error:

```
DBCException: Invalid number of points in LineString (found 1 - must be 0 or >= 2)
```

Anyone a suggestion what I'm missing?

Comment: Could it be that a few `gps.point_id` have only a single coordinate pair?

Comment: I have included a screenshot of my table, hope that clarifies my question a bit

Comment: Never post data as images, we can hardly work with it. Alwasys post data as text. In your screenshot there is only one coordinate pair per index, so you cannot create line strings by grouping with `index`. Or you want to create a single line with all records of the table?

Comment: You're right, thought this could clarify your question though. Exactly, I would like to create a single line with all records of the table

Comment: Before I elaborate more in an answer, can you try this and tell me if it is what you want? `SELECT ST_MakeLine(point_geom ORDER BY index) FROM gps_points;`

Comment: Difficult to tell if this is what I want, as I have troubles to view the query as a layer in Qgis. But the points represent a route that I would like to store in a table in my database and visualize in Qgis

Comment: I will add more details in an answer and we can go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot we can see that there is only a single record per `index` (which is btw not a recommended label for a column) and the error message says that you need more than one point in order to have a proper `LineString`. That being said, you have to either look for another column to `GROUP BY` your points, or just create a single line with the entire table:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(point_geom ORDER BY index) FROM gps_points;
```

Example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE gps_points (
  index SERIAL,
  latitude NUMERIC,
  longitude NUMERIC
);
```

Inserting three distinct points

```
INSERT INTO gps_points VALUES 
  (1,52.37,4.92),(2,52.37,4.93),(3,52.375,4.92);
```

Creating the geometry column and populating it as you posted

```
ALTER TABLE gps_points ADD COLUMN point_geom geometry(Point, 4326);
UPDATE gps_points SET point_geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

Creating a LineString based on the three points above

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(point_geom ORDER BY index) FROM gps_points;
```

[image]

If you need to create a table to access it from a GIS, just run ..

```
CREATE TABLE my_long_linestring AS
SELECT ST_MakeLine(point_geom ORDER BY index) FROM gps_points;
```

.. and open this new table in your GIS:

[image]

**Note**: PostGIS will allow you to create a LineString with a single point (see example bellow), but it would maybe create other problems in your system.. specially in viewers.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine('SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)'::geometry));
    st_astext    
-----------------
 LINESTRING(1 2)
```

Comment: That's a much simpler solution I was looking for, thanks a lot!